# FixedPoint not working, despite quick convergence of sequence

Tags: functions, machine-precision, infinite-loop, iteration

Trying the computation below, with *Mathematica* 13.0.0, I am not getting a result returned.

```
FixedPoint[Cos, 0.85]
```

This appears in the 3rd edition of "Programming with Mathematica" (Wellin et al.), as a straightforward application.

Can someone explain what is going on?

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Have you tried with a fresh kernel (by using ``Quit[]`` first)? I get the [result instantly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3G1K.png).

Comment: Yes I have tried `Quit[]`, and restarted Mathematica. OS is MacOS 11.6.4

Comment: What is the output of `FixedPointList[Cos, 0.85]` ? What is `MachinePrecision` ?

Comment: I'm getting the same thing - FixedPoint[Cos, 0.85] does not return a value. A simple workaround is FixedPoint[Cos, 0.85, 100] which does return.

Comment: `MachinePrecision` is 15.9546. I have never messed with any settings. FixedPointLIst is not returning.

Comment: MMA version 13.0.1 I get a result of: 0.739085

Comment: Works fine on "13.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)"

Comment: @S.V Try inspecting the last elements of `FixedPointList[Cos, 0.85, 100] // InputForm`.

Comment: S.V., please try what @SjoerdSmit suggested and show your results (here are [mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baLWZ.png) for example). As others have pointed out, the problem might be due to different implementations of numeric algorithms for your processor. We can diagnose that by looking at your results, which will probably oscillate between two values (for example 0.7390851332151607 and 0.7390851332151606).

Comment: It oscillates between 0.7390851332151605 and 0.7390851332151608 from the 88th position.

Comment: `$Version` is `13.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)" *)
```

The `Possible Issues` section of the documentation for [`FixedPoint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixedPoint.html) states "Convergence may fail in machine-precision computations due to oscillations in the final digits. Use a test function with a larger tolerance than SameQ to resolve this:" and gives the example

```
FixedPoint[Cos, 0.5, SameTest -> Equal]

(* 0.739085 *)
```

Likewise,

```
FixedPoint[Cos, 0.85, SameTest -> Equal]

(* 0.739085 *)
```

**EDIT:**

```
FixedPointList[Cos, 0.85, 100][[-15 ;;]] // FullForm
```

[image]

For my hardware/firmware/software combination, once the result hits `0.7390851332151605` it oscillates between that value and `0.7390851332151608` (differing in only the last decimal digit). These two values fail a [`SameQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ.html) test ("SameQ requires exact correspondence between expressions, except that it still considers Real numbers equal if they differ in their last binary digit.").  However, they do pass an [`Equal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html) test ("Approximate numbers with machine precision or higher are considered equal if they differ in at most their last seven binary digits (roughly their last two decimal digits)".

I do not consider the use of a documented option to be a "workaround" anymore than having to specify a non-default `PlotRange` when a plot doesn't give the range that you want. Options exist because they are expected to be used. If you want the `Equal` test to be the default behavior, add that to your [`init.m`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/file/init.m.html) file.

Comment: I appreciate that workarounds exist, but other users don't need them. Can you explain why this is the case, and if there is a fix for it? My hardware is not that bad (iMac 4GHz I7 Quad Core, 32GB Ram) and judging from the timing results submitted it appears to be a very simple computation.

Comment: @S.V This kind of oscillation need not arise from "bad" hardware. I would more expect it from "good" hardware, that has 80 bit registers. I've seen this type of issue in such cases, typically from an extra precision computation getting truncated when stored in regular 64 bit memory.

Comment: @S.V Machine numbers are fast but tricky. You cannot expect identical results from different implementations of floating point arithmetic. This is an area where you must be mindful of what you're trying to accomplish and how the approximate nature of numerical computation may affect that goal.